# Explicit solution formula for a nonlinear sequence

Tags: integer-sequences

I have a sequence defined as follows
$$u_1=2, \quad u_{n+1}=nu_n+2.$$

And I want to compute (if possible) the explicit solution.

Comment: This sequence is [A054091](http://oeis.org/A054091) in the OEIS. Some explicit formulas are given there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very particular case of a general difference equation of order one of the form
$$
u_{n+1}=p_{n}u_{n}+q_{n},
$$
where $(p_{n}), (q_{n})$ are given sequences. The solution is given by:
$$
u_{n}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}p_{i}\right)u_{1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\prod_{j=i+1}^{n-1}p_{j}\right)q_{i}
$$
In your case $p_{n}=n, q_{n}=2$, and after necessary simplifications, one can easily get
$$
u_{n}=2\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{j!}.
$$

Comment: Which is $2 e \Gamma (n,1)$